# Overlay over image without position absolute

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to replicate the following without using `position:absolute`: [image]

The reason I can't use position absolute is because the form div has a sibling that needs to be under it and I can't figure out how to offset the sibling to make it look natural.

Heres a js fiddle of what it current does
http://jsfiddle.net/c4ww6hs4/

I would like to avoid using JS if possible.

Comment: Use a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative `margin-top`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4ww6hs4/1/)